# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' - BeautifulSoup to CSV

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, attributeerror, html-parser

I am trying to make a webscraper that looks through multiple pages to make a csv list for me. When I run the basic of the code it works, but when I have it iterate to go to multiple pages I get a AttributeError:

assignees=assignees_elem.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

The csv is saved but blank.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import *
import csv


pagenumber = 0


file = open('newcsv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file)

while pagenumber <50:
    pagenumber += 1
    pagenumbers = str(pagenumber)
    
    URL = 'website'+pagenumbers
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    site_elems = soup.find_all('div', class_='meta')
    writer.writerow(['Number', 'Issued', 'Assignees', 'Inventors'])
    
    for site_elem in site_elems:
        number_elem = site_elem.find('div', class_='number')
        issued_elem=site_elem.find('div', class_='date-issued')
        assignees_elem=site_elem.find('div', class_='assignees')
        inventors_elem=site_elem.find('div', class_='inventors')
        number=number_elem.text.strip()
        issued=issued_elem.text.strip()
        assignees=assignees_elem.text.strip()
        inventors=inventors_elem.text.strip()
        print (number + ' ' + issued +' ' + assignees + ' ' + inventors)
        writer.writerow([number.encode('utf-8'),issued.encode('utf-8'), assignees.encode('utf-8'),inventors.encode('utf-8')])
        
file.close()
```

Comment: It seems `assignees_elem=site_elem.find('div', class_='assignees')` get nothing.

Comment: I solved it by adding ```if None in (number_elem, issued_elem, assignees_elem, inventors_elem):
            continue```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding

`if None in (number_elem, issued_elem, assignees_elem, inventors_elem):             continue`